# Python: Type error 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, for-loop, floating-point, iterable

My code is :

```
for ep in range(10):
    for x, y in tqdm(train_iterator.gen_batches(batch_size=64, 
                                           data_type="train")):
        x_embed = embedder(tokenizer(str_lower(x)))
        y_onehot = onehotter(classes_vocab(y))
        cls.train_on_batch(x_embed, y_onehot)
```

and the result :

```
<ipython-input-30-3f8c38399ce9> in <module>()
      2     for x, y in tqdm(train_iterator.gen_batches(batch_size=64, 
      3                                            data_type="train")):
----> 4         x_embed = embedder(tokenizer(str_lower(x)))
      5         y_onehot = onehotter(classes_vocab(y))
      6         cls.train_on_batch(x_embed, y_onehot)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/deeppavlov/models/preprocessors/str_lower.py in str_lower(batch)
     31         return batch.lower()
     32     else:
---> 33         return list(map(str_lower, batch))

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

I have tried to change it to ep = int [float] but this doesn't work either.

Comment: You `x` is of `float` type but it should be a `string` or other iterable type present in python such as list or tuple , as I can understand from the given information.

Comment: thankyou for giving review on my post. But how to converse x as a string by my code?

Comment: What do you expect the `x` and `y` produced by iterating `tqdm(...)` to be?  We don't know anything about your data or data generator.  Why is `x` a number, when the rest of the code expects a string or list of strings?  Don't blindly throw patches into your code - focus on understanding, not patches.

Answer (score 0):

`str_lower()` takes either a string as an argument or an iterable type and calls `.lower()` on it. However in your code `x` is of type float. 
So whenever `list()` is called with `x` as an argument it returns this error:

```
>>> list(3.14)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    list(3.14)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

So you either want to:

- Make sure `x` is a string
- Not call `str_lower(x)`

Comment: thankyou for giving review on my post. But how to converse x as a string by my code?

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to do with your code but do you expect x to be a string? Would `embedder(tokenizer(x))` not work? OR you could do `str(x)` to convert it to string, in that case you don't need to call `str_lower()` and it'll be `embedder(tokenizer(str(x)))`. But again, I do not know what your code does exactly. Hope this helps.